# Why isn't @JmsListener in ActiveMQ working?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

First, I made [a test project](https://github.com/stavatar/TestJMSActiveMQ) to learn how to work with ActiveMQ. Everything worked there.

But when I did the same with [an already made application](https://github.com/stavatar/Lab3Buisness) on Spring + security + JAAS then everything stopped working, and apparently the `JmsListener` class is not working. I sent messages to this queue via ActiveMQ admin but didn't work.

Comment: Why are you using JmsConfig? This is all default

Comment: You mean that all the settings are already default? Well, just in case. I did it according to different tutorials and there was this. But this is unlikely to be a mistake

Comment: Exaclty. You don't have to configure. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-activemq You can also remove the activemq-broker dependency Please try this first and if doesn't work come back

Comment: I updated project on github.The error remains

Comment: You say both that "everything stopped working" and that the `JmsListener` didn't get the message you sent. Did something other than the `JmsListener` stop working or is the `JmsListener` "everything" here? Please clarify. Also, did you see any error messages or exceptions anywhere?

Comment: Also, why do your projects have environment-specific or build-time resources checked in (e.g. `.idea` directory, `target` directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ist this line

```
@ComponentScan({"com.*"})
```

You don't need this as long as all Beans are in the same package or in a package below where the SpringBootApplication is.

So remove this line